# How can I call a function from the parent component with an event in the child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-state

I'm busy learning React and one of the tasks is building a game where the cards shuffle on each try. The card array and the shuffle method are in a parent component (I use map to render the cards), but the retry button is in the child component.

I've read almost 20 StackOverflow questions and many docs, but somehow my logic is simply not working.

Can someone please help me to get this to work.

Parent:

```
import React from 'react'
import FlipCard from './FlipCard'

const cards = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'NOPE',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: `!!WIN-
        NER!!`,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'NOPE',
    },
]

const shuffle = array => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        const temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = temp
    }
    return array
}

const shuffleCards = shuffle(cards)

const CardGameUI = () => {
    return (
        <div className="cards-ui">
            {cards.map(card => (
                <FlipCard
                    key={card.id}
                    text={card.text}
                    value={card.id}
                    shuffleCards={shuffleCards}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardGameUI
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCardFlip from 'react-card-flip'
import FrontComponent from './FrontComponent'
import BackComponent from './BackComponent'
import RetryModal from './RetryModal'

class FlipCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isFlipped: false,
            gamesPlayed: 0,
            gamesWon: 0,
            gamesLost: 0,
            show: false,
            gameMsg: '',
        }

        this.handleFlip = this.handleFlip.bind(this)
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this)
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this)
        this.handleRetry = this.handleRetry.bind(this)
    }

    handleReset() {
        this.setState({
            isFlipped: false,
            gamesPlayed: 0,
            gamesWon: 0,
            gamesLost: 0,
            show: false,
            gameMsg: '',
        })
        this.props.shuffleCards
    }

    handleRetry() {
        this.setState({
            isFlipped: false,
            show: false,
            gameMsg: '',
        })
        this.props.shuffleCards
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
        })
    }
    handleShow() {
        this.setState({
            show: true,
        })
    }

    handleFlip() {
        this.setState({
            isFlipped: true,
            gamesPlayed: +1,
            show: false,
        })

        if (this.props.value !== 2) {
            this.setState({
                gamesLost: 0,
                gameMsg:
                    'It looks like you lost this round. Want to play another?',
            })
        } else if (this.props.value === 2) {
            this.setState({
                gamesWon: 0,
                gameMsg: 'CONGRATULATIONS!!!. Want to win again?',
            })
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.handleShow()
        }, 1000)
    }

    render() {
        const text = this.props.text
        const value = this.props.value
        const isFlipped = this.state.isFlipped

        return (
            <>
                <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
                    <FrontComponent onClick={this.handleFlip} />

                    <BackComponent text={text} value={value} />
                </ReactCardFlip>

                <RetryModal
                    handleShow={this.handleShow}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    handleReset={this.handleReset}
                    handleRetry={this.handleRetry}
                    show={this.state.show}
                    text={this.state.gameMsg}
                />
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default FlipCard
```

I included all the code from these two components as I wasn't sure what will help clarify.

Essentially the shuffleCards method needs to run when handleReset and handleRetry are triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have 3 problems:

1. the `shuffleCards` prop you were passing down was not actually a function, but the *result* of calling the function that shuffles the cards.
2. You seem to recognise the above by doing `this.props.shuffleCards` in the
   child component - rather than `this.props.shuffleCards()` which here
   would cause an error since `this.props.shuffleCards` is not a
   function. But that is itself an admission of the problem, because
   you clearly need to call a function here, in order to make anything
   happen.
3. The function itself doesn't actually create a new shuffled array, but mutates the old one. Yes, it then returns that, but by returning the old object, even in mutated form, React won't be able to see a change and therefore won't know that the array has been mutated.

So here's how to solve. First, make the card array a state variable in the parent function, and make `shuffleCards` an actual function, that lives in the parent component (because it needs to access the current `cards` state), and one that, rather than simply mutating the old array of cards, makes a new array and updates the state with it.

Here's the new parent component, and note that the `shuffle` and `shuffleCards` values you've defined outside it are no longer needed or wanted:

```
const CardGameUI = () => {
    const [shuffledCards, setShuffledCards] = React.useState(cards);

    const shuffleCards = (currentCards) => {
        const array = [...currentCards]; // this makes a (shallow) copy of the array, so it's recognised by React as something new
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
            const temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[j]
            array[j] = temp
        }
        setShuffledCards(array);
    };

    return (
        <div className="cards-ui">
            {shuffledCards.map(card => (
                <FlipCard
                    key={card.id}
                    text={card.text}
                    value={card.id}
                    shuffleCards={shuffleCards}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then you need to update the child component so that it actually calls this state-updating function, by changing as I indicated in point 2) above: replace `this.props.shuffleCards` with `this.props.shuffleCards()`.

The cards should now be correctly shuffled when the appropriate actions are taken in the child component. (And let me know if anything still doesn't work as intended - I haven't actually tested this out.)

Comment: Thank you very for taking the time to explain this. It never occurred to me that I can setState to an array and I also never knew about creating the shallow copy - MUCH APPRECIATED. Now I'm getting the error at `const array = [...currentCards]` is not iterable. From what I've researched, this is usually an error that applies to for...of loops so not sure how to fix it in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JC_vd_Merwe_03 apologies, looks like I messed up the formatting of the code sample. That's fixed now - it's possible you had something wrong by not realising that I was giving you revised code for the whole component. With `cards` as it is in your original post, defined as an array of objects outside the component, I do not see how you could get the error you are describing, so I hope it was just my poor formatting that was to blame. If it still doesn't work, please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for the reformat, I wasn't sure about it but then implemented it like you have it now in any-case because it made sense. So, what I added to make the final difference was `shuffleCards = {() => shuffleCards(cards)}` and that seemed to do the trick. Thank you again for creating so much understanding in your answer.

Comment: oh yes, apologies, I'd overlooked that it needed to take no arguments. Sorry for that, and glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [...cards];
const shuffle = () => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        const temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = temp
    }
    return array
}
```

Just replace shuffle function by this code !
I hope it works !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have a look at what @RobinZigmond did above.